# Global Event Listener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there any way by which I can make my button work, no matter in which scene or frame it is. 
Is there any way by which i can call that Event Listener to another frame for that particular instance?

for example:
I have a button `home_btn`, I want this button to work in all scenes, without changing it's instance name. I already added an Event listener in first scene, but it doesn't work,
In another frame or scene.
Below is the code.

```
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, process_it);

function process_it(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextFrame();
}
```

I don't know how to use dispatch event function for my button.
// This only works for that particular frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing this in the timeline, if you put the `home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, process_it);`

on the first frame of your main timeline, it will be registered even if you change to a different frame.

You can keep the function in its existing frame as that should still be called.

The reason why this works as opposed to the code being on a different frame is because frame 1 is where your timeline will start and process all the display items and code needed during this frame. That is any function, variable, or listener you want active will be running and/or stored into memory at the start of the application since it will always start on frame 1 until specified otherwise. If you have the listener on a different frame then you will have to `gotoAndStop()` to that frame to add the listener ( otherwise you are specifying that you don't want to add the listener until your application is at the frame ). Adding a listener to a display object on frame 1 is contingent upon the display object also being on that frame.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.
But I still have a question, if it is not on frame 1 then it doesn't work. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Sure I'll add it into my answer. Please mark it correct if this fixes your problem in case others are having the same issue.

Comment: Having object in another scene with same instance name doesn't work, if the Event Listener is defined in Scene 1, Frame 1.

Comment: Yes your display object needs to exist on the same frame as the event declaration. But you said you wanted it on each frame. If your button doesn't exist on frame 1 then you'll need to put the `home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, process_it);` on the frame where it does exist. I added a clause to the answer stating this as well.

Comment: That means, I have to define different Event listeners with different instance name for different scenes on the first frame, to make it work. Isn't.

Comment: Well, i think `dispatchEvent` may work. But I don't know how to use it for button events.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what all is going on in your timelines so my fix is treating the symptoms here. I can't speak about how your doing these events and how/where you want to use `dispatchEvent`. That's the downside to doing actionscript in the timeline, it becomes hard to diagnose. There are plenty of examples of `dispatchEvent` if you want to try that, but you are still going to have to add the listeners to your objects to use `dispatchEvent`.